# How to convert all variables in a list of df to character

Tags: r

I have list of dfs `lst1`. Now I would like to change every variables in all dfs in `lst` to character. How can I do that?

Please list as many way as possible. Thanks. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `tidvyerse` approach

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(lst1, ~ .x %>%
                 mutate(across(everything(), as.character)))
```

Answer (score 4):

**1)** If L is the list of data frames use rapply

```
rapply(L, as.character, how = "replace")
```

**2)** or lapply over the list and for each data frame lapply over the columns.

```
lapply(L, function(x) replace(x, TRUE, lapply(x, as.character)))
```